# How can i replace FusedLocationApi with FusedLocationProviderClient?

Tags: android, google-maps, location, fusedlocationproviderapi

I want to find current location on connected. I am currently using FusedLocationApi which is deprecated. i have to use requestLocationUpdate method but i am getting some syntax error while using FusedLocationProviderClient. i also have to use removeLocationupdate in onPause and onDestroy.

This is my current code which is using FusedLocationProviderClient-

```
@Override
public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
    mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(1000);
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(1000);

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
        return;
    }
   LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleClientApi, mLocationRequest, this);
    if (mCurrentLocMarker == null) {
        Location loc = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleClientApi);
        mLastLocation = loc;
        if (loc != null) {
            LatLng latLng = new LatLng(loc.getLatitude(), loc.getLongitude());
            MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
            markerOptions.position(latLng);
            markerOptions.title("Current Location");
            markerOptions.flat(true);
            int height = 150;
            int width = 150;
            BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = (BitmapDrawable)getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_navigation);
            Bitmap bitmap = bitmapDrawable.getBitmap();
            Bitmap marker = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, width, height, false);
            markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(marker));
            markerOptions.anchor(0.5f, 0.5f);
            mCurrentLocMarker = mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
            CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                    .target(latLng)
                    .zoom(17)
                    .build();
            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
        }

    }
}
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mapView.onPause();
    String trackid = SharedPreferenceManager.getmInstance(this).getTrackId();
    if (mGoogleClientApi != null) {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleClientApi,this);
    }
    if (!trackid.equals("NO DATA")) {
        startService(new Intent(this, LocationService.class));
    }
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    mapView.onDestroy();
    String trackid = SharedPreferenceManager.getmInstance(this).getTrackId();
    if (mGoogleClientApi != null) {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleClientApi, this);
    }
    if (!trackid.equals("NO DATA")) {
        startService(new Intent(this, LocationService.class));
    }
}
```

This is i tried but cannot implement its requestLocationUpdate and removeLocationUpdate:

```
FusedLocationProviderClient fusedLocationProviderClient; //Global variable
fusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this); //initiate in onCreate
```

Answer (score 2):

Your start is like you need.

```
FusedLocationProviderClient fusedLocationProviderClient; //Global variable
fusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this); //initiate in onCreate
```

For getting location from another app as googlemaps you can use `mFusedLocationClient.getLastLocation()` it have listeners, `addOnSuccessListener` gives to you location, `addOnCompleteListener` and `task.getResult() == null` means that you need to do your own request like `mFusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(getLocationRequest(), mLocationCallback, null);`

and you need to remove your listener for example in onPause like `mFusedLocationClient.removeLocationUpdates(mLocationCallback)`

you can look this examples https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-location
and https://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates?hl=es

Comment: Yes, i got it this things but i am little bit confuse about mLocationCallback

Comment: Its object LocationCallback from `com.google.android.gms.location.LocationCallback;` and you need to make it like `new LocationCallback()` and it gives you to override method  `onLocationResult` with locationResult. If your `locationResult == null` the location service is turned off, and you need to resolve it. In other case you need  for by locationResult.getLocations() and you will get location.getLatitude() and location.getLongitude()