# Android - My app can get location information until opening Google Maps although it has related permissions

Tags: android, android-manifest

I am new in Android development. So my question may be too basic. Sorry for this. Now I am maintaining a previously written code.

This application use the location services of the phone. In the manifest file it is written:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
```

But although users give permisson for using location services, in most cases by application can not get location directly.

For example while my app can not get location information, after opening Google Maps application, my application can always get  the location information. Then I have no problem with location.But firstly I have to trigger with Google Maps.

What could cause this? Why my app can get location after opening Google Maps? Do I need another permission in my manifest file?

My code block is like the following ,

```
private static final int LOCATION_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 9001;

private void initMainActivity() {

        int fineAccessGranted = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
        int coarseAccessGranted = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION);
        int externalWrite = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        int externalRead = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        int camera = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.CAMERA);

        ArrayList<String> permissionsNeeded = new ArrayList<String>();

        if (fineAccessGranted == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED)
            permissionsNeeded.add(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
        if (coarseAccessGranted == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED)
            permissionsNeeded.add(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION);
        if (externalWrite == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED)
            permissionsNeeded.add(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        if (externalRead == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED)
            permissionsNeeded.add(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        if (camera == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED)
            permissionsNeeded.add(Manifest.permission.CAMERA);

        if (permissionsNeeded.size() == 0) {
            this.initMainActivityAfterPermissions();
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, permissionsNeeded.toArray(new String[0]), LOCATION_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST);
        }
    }


public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        // super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        switch (requestCode) {
            case LOCATION_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST: {
                // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
                if (grantResults.length > 0
                        && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                    this.initMainActivityAfterPermissions();

                } else {

                }
                return;
            }
```

Code fragment that gets the location;

```
result =  LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(instance.mGoogleApiClient);
```

Comment: How are you retrieving the location information? Do you have some code to show?

Comment: @GiovanniTerlingen I added to code to my question detail

Comment: Show the code for fetching location. What you've provided is just the permission check

Comment: @HarishJose added at the end of question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically it means that you try to retrieve location via `mFusedLocationClient.getLastLocation()` and there is no location on device at this time. So you need to request location updates , like `mFusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates`.
This links will be useful https://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates?hl=es and https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-location

Comment: @VadimEskler I have a code snippte like for getting location ;  result =  LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(instance.mGoogleApiClient); How must I edit this ? Can you help me  please ?

Comment: First the FusedLocationApi is deprecated, so you need to change it with FusedLocationClient. And then you can look to my this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53274574/how-can-i-replace-fusedlocationapi-with-fusedlocationproviderclient/53276685#53276685

Comment: @VadimEskler Sorry again. I want to ask something. I understand that this method is async. Is there a sync version of this method. Because I want to stop my code execution until getlastlocation returns. How can I handle ?

Comment: It's totally async because there are a lot of cases that you wont get location.

Comment: Sorry for basic questions. How can I stop code execution until this method returns answer ? Because I have to sent the location server after taking it.

Comment: the question - what exactly you want to make after you will get location data. As I write, it will be very bad for user if you will show progress 2 minutes until you get current location, and what will be in very bad case, for example user underground floor -3 for example, you would get his location...

Comment: I will list the users according to their locations. Firstly I will get the location then will sent this location server and server will return user list according to from nearest to far

Comment: so why you can't do this? you show map with no actions, when you will get the location and server result you can update map.

Comment: Many Thanks for your help. I will try it