# Why is the location getTime lagging by 2-3 minutes

Tags: android, geolocation

I am listening to location Updates by using

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000, 0, this);
```

and when I get the location in

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(final Location location)
{
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("E MM/dd/yyyy   hh:mm:ss a");
    Log.d("OnLocationChange: ", dateFormat.format(location.getTime());
}
```

The date and time displayed is 2 to 3 minutes delayed. Can someone tell me why

Comment: Is it in background (Service)?

Comment: gps will take time to take the location. specially for the first time to locate exact position. also that depends on the GPS signal strength ,hardware etc.

Comment: Go for the FusedLocationProvider it will return last known location much quicker

Answer (score 0):

I advise you to use new FusedLocationProviderClient, it's more stable and faster than old api's, also it easy to use. You can look at my example here [Android - My app can get location information until opening Google Maps although it has related permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53276698/android-my-app-can-get-location-information-until-opening-google-maps-although/53276863#53276863), there i put links to documentations.

Comment: I changed my code to use FusedLocationProviderClient but there is still a 2-3 Minute delay.

Comment: And you use `mFusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates` what is your LocationRequest settings that you send to this function, first parameter?

Comment: do you use two manifest permission as `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` and `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION`?

Answer (score 0):

For these case use

```
getElapsedRealtimeNanos() //Return the time of this fix, in elapsed real-time since system boot
```

refer

[getTime vs getElapsedRealtimeNanos in Location](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#getElapsedRealtimeNanos())