# Can't get location by Network provider in Oreo

Tags: android, gps, location

I want to get location from GPS provider and network provider. I wrote below code and works correct in android below 6 and i checked in android 4.2 and everything is correct but when i checked in android 8 till GPS is on, everything is worked and i get location by network or GPS. but when GPS is off, i can't get location by Network provider. What is my problem and How can i solved this? Do on API 23+, needs enable GPS for get location? Do i need enable an option in settings of my device?

```
public void createLocation(){
locationManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
gpsLocListener = new MyLocationListener();
networkLocListener = new MyLocationListener();
}

...
 public static void checkLocation() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
        if ((ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) && ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, networkLocListener);
        }
    } else {
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, networkLocListener);
    }

    if (!FIND_LOC_ByY_GPS) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
            if ((ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)&& ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, networkLocListener);                }
        } else {
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, networkLocListener);            }
        //locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(locationManager.PASSIVE_PROVIDER,0,0,passiveLocListener);
    }
}

public static class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {

    public MyLocationListener() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        if (location != null && !callLocationUpdate) {
            //Speed
            //if (calculateSpeedUser(location) < 13.8889) {
            try {
                removeLocationUpdate();
                callLocationUpdate = true;
                if (DEBUG_BASEACTIVITY)
                    Log.e("GPS Location Changed!", "onLocationChanged/BaseActivity");

            } catch (SecurityException e) {
                Log.e("PERMISSION_EXCEPTION", "PERMISSION_NOT_GRANTED");
            }
            //}
            get_location_by_LocationUpdate_method = true;
            doLocationUpdate(location, true);
            getByLocationUpdate = true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

    }
}
```

Comment: First of all I suggest you use actual API - FusedLocationClient. Take a look my answer here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/53276863/7917629, there are two useful links.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but i can't use another API. I want to solve this problem and i want to know, why in android 8 with GPS offline, network provider can't get location?

Comment: FusedLocationProviderClient is recommended android location API, why you can't use it? Anyway, I tried to use old location api on android 7-8 it almost not worked.