# Android: Location updating very slowly

Tags: android, gps, location

I am trying to create an app that sends to my server the location of my android device on button press. Unfortunately the location updates very slowly, sometimes taking minutes and tens of meters to get the new location.

I'm relatively new to Android programming and if anyone could help me with a way to update the location every time when press the send button I would be grateful.

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;

import org.json.*;

import java.io.IOException;

import okhttp3.Call;
import okhttp3.Callback;
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.Request;
import okhttp3.Response;

import static android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION;

public class DefaultActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private String serverURL;
    private TextView tv_Title, tv_Status;
    private Button b_SendLocation, b_SendNow, b_StopLocation;
    private User user;
    private FusedLocationProviderClient locationClient;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_default);
        Intent intent = getIntent();

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 1);
        locationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);

        serverURL = intent.getExtras().getString("serverURL");
        JSONParse(intent.getExtras().getString("myResponse"));

        tv_Title = findViewById(R.id.TextView_Title);
        tv_Status = findViewById(R.id.TextView_Status);
        b_SendLocation = findViewById(R.id.Button_SendLocation);
        b_SendNow = findViewById(R.id.Button_SendNow);
        b_StopLocation = findViewById(R.id.Button_StopLocation);

        tv_Title.setText(user.getLastName() + " " + user.getFirstName());
        tv_Status.setText(" ");

        b_SendLocation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Feedback("Sending location every 5 sec.");
            }

        });

        b_SendNow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Feedback("Current location sent!");
                GetLocation();
            }

        });

        b_StopLocation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Feedback("Periodic sending halted!");
            }

        });
    }


    private void GetLocation() {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(DefaultActivity.this, ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }

        locationClient.getLastLocation().addOnSuccessListener(DefaultActivity.this, new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Location location) {
                if(location != null){
                    double latitude, longitude;
                    latitude = location.getLatitude();
                    longitude = location.getLongitude();
                    tv_Status.setText("Latitude: " + latitude + "\nLongitude: " + longitude);
                    SendLocation(latitude, longitude);
                }
                else
                    tv_Status.setText("Location is null!");
            }
        });
    }

    private void SendLocation(double latitude, double longitude){
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        String url = serverURL + "/api/user/?id=" + user.getID() + "&latitude=" + latitude + "&longitude=" + longitude;

        Request request = new Request.Builder().url(url).build();
        client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        tv_Status.append("\n\n Server error!");
                    }
                });
            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException{
                if (response.isSuccessful()){
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            tv_Status.append("\n\n Server acknowledged!");
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void JSONParse(String JSONString){
        User readUser = new User();
        try {
            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(JSONString);

            readUser.setID(Integer.parseInt(obj.getString("ID")));
            readUser.setFirstName(obj.getString("FirstName"));
            readUser.setLastName(obj.getString("LastName"));
            readUser.setEmail(obj.getString("Email"));
            readUser.setPassword(obj.getString("Password"));
            readUser.setRole(obj.getString("Role"));

            Feedback("Welcome back " + readUser.getFirstName() + "!");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Feedback("JSON Exception!");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        user = readUser;
    }

    private void Feedback(String message){
        Toast toast=Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),message,Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Take a look my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53276698/android-my-app-can-get-location-information-until-opening-google-maps-although/53276863#53276863 I think it same problem, you try to get last location from other apps, and you can create your own request  and not wait for them.

Comment: Thank you this answer helped me a lot!