# FusedLocationProviderClient sometimes doesn't return the location

Tags: android, android-fusedlocation, fusedlocationproviderclient

I want to make an app in Android Studio which returns the location of the user. This is the code I am using:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_location);
FusedLocationProviderClient fusedLocationProviderClient = new FusedLocationProviderClient(LocationActivity.this);
fusedLocationProviderClient.getLastLocation().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(final Location location)
            {
                    if (location != null)
                    {
                        latitude= location.getLatitude();
                        longitude = location.getLongitude();
            latitudeStr=String.valueOf(latitude);
            longitudeStr=String.valueOf(longitude);
            Toast.makeText(LocationActivity.this,latitudeStr+" "+longitudeStr , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  
        }
        else {
                        Toast.makeText(SearchActivity.this, "Your Location Could Not Be Found !!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
    }
```

}

Now sometimes it is returning the right location but sometimes it shows the Toast message  "Your Location Could Not Be Found !!!" which I think implies that it is not getting the location. Please tell me a way in which the app will always return the location of the user.

Comment: take look here, https://stackoverflow.com/a/53276863/7917629 you take just last, and in case that exist you need to make self request.

Comment: Could you tell me what do you mean by self request?